# How can I skip cells in an html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make an online board game and for this, I want the cells to go around the board. Does anyone know how I can skip the cells in the middle? So far, I have tried using `&nbsp;` but that is not really working.

Here is a sample of my code:

```css
#board {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  height: 375px;
  width: 889px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
        <tr>
            <td class="square">Start!</td>
            <td class="square">Text!</td>
            <td class="square">text?</td>
            <td class="square">text</td>
            <td class="square">cool text</td>
            <td class="square">text!!!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="square">text</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="square">text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="square">text</td>
            <td class="square">text</td>
            <td class="square">text.</td>
            <td class="square">very cool text</td>
            <td class="square">text?</td>
            <td class="square">text!!!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: By using colspan?

Comment: Is your number of columns static? Or will the number of columns shown change depending on the data, time of date, size of the browser window, etc.?

Comment: The entire board is static and pretty much doesn't change throughout the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you're talking about something like this where you're just missing the `colspan` and removing the `float` if I'm understanding right. Here's some [more playing you can do with tables](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/LYPKZWQ) if that's your design choice.

```css
#board {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: forestgreen;
/*
  height: 375px;
  width: 889px;
*/
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 20px;
}

#center-tile {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/700) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
    <tr>
        <td class="square">Start!</td>
        <td class="square">Text!</td>
        <td class="square">text?</td>
        <td class="square">text</td>
        <td class="square">cool text</td>
        <td class="square">text!!!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="square">text</td>
        <td id="center-tile" rowspan="2" colspan="4">Center</td>
        <td class="square">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="square">text</td>
        <td class="square">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="square">text</td>
        <td class="square">text</td>
        <td class="square">text.</td>
        <td class="square">very cool text</td>
        <td class="square">text?</td>
        <td class="square">text!!!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran the code and it works almost perfectly! However, the squares are now separated, is there any way I can make them touch perfectly?

Comment: @LitFishie121 see updated answer, and if I might suggest check out [some resources](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) on the html table basics. Notice the added `rowspan` per your request. Semantics are important :)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help! :)
I will check out the provided resources